# android mupdf libmupdf.so runtime error "No implementation found for native openFile"

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk, native-methods, libs

I just finished compiling mupdf from mupdf.com on my mac. Took some time to figure it out but now I have a libmupdf.so in my libs/armeabi folder.

They provide an example of this class called MuPDFCore.java which is viewable here:
http://mupdf.com/repos/mupdf/android/src/com/artifex/mupdf/MuPDFCore.java

I used this class in my project and it says the following in LogCat:

> Trying to load lib
>   /data/data/com.myapp.android/lib/libmupdf.so
>   0x4070e050
>
> Added shared lib
>   /data/data/com.myapp.android/lib/libmupdf.so
>   0x4070e050
>
> No JNI_OnLoad found in
>   /data/data/com.myapp.android/lib/libmupdf.so
>   0x4070e050, skipping init
>
> No implementation found for native
>   Lcom/myapp/android/viewer/MuPDFCore;.openFile
>   (Ljava/lang/String;)I
>
> DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(27523): Shutting
>   down VM
>
> WARN/dalvikvm(27523): threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x400ee760)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27523): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27523):
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   openFile

As far as I know the library is loading, before I figured out how to compile the library it kept crashing and saying the "mupdf" is a null link.

Their example pretty much says that openFile is a native function ... Just when I thought I figured this out another problem pops up. Ive been working on it all day. Any input would be great!

Is it a bad compile? I didn't get any errors in the terminal.

Comment: Ah ha! I just figured it out. I looked at mupdf.c and realized there were similarly named functions but they had this long prefix. I realized that the prefix is also a package name. So I put the MUPDFCore back into the com.artifex.mupdf package and it works!

Comment: Please explain your solution, i have been stuck in this problem for a whole day now :(

Answer (score 10):

when you try to use it on your project with sample project's so files, it will throw **"UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found"** exception. The cause is your app package name different from sample app package name("com.artifex.mupdf") because of jni binding system. You can solve this problem with below approaches:

1) long way: change mudef lib source code according to your package name, generate binaries(.so files) from it then use it in your project like @KuoCH said

2) short way: create "com.artifex.mupdf" package in your root source directory(beside project source folder, "src/main/java"), copy all classes from sample project to in it

Answer (score 5):

At file mupdf.c L18-19:

```
#define JNI_FN(A) Java_com_artifex_mupdfdemo_ ## A 
#define PACKAGENAME "com/artifex/mupdfdemo"
```

Change both to your package name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't change the your function names in mupdf.c to your corresponding java package name, that means, you should change the function Java_com_artifex_mupdf_MuPDFCore_openFile in your mupdf.c to Java_com_myapp_android_viewer_openFile.